# Python Tkinter build commands from array

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build a menu out of given array, where the label and command are based on the array item.

```
arr1 = ["item0","item1","item2"]
for arg in arr1:
    self.menu.add_command(label=arg, command= lambda: print(arg))
```

With the above code the labels works fine, but all the entries commands are printing the same text of the last arg (item2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple workaround to that:
Use `lambda` like this:

```
self.menu.add_command(label=arg, command= lambda x=arg: print(x))
```